# Random spam code found while 'Inspecting' or 'Viewing Source' on my website

Tags: php, spam-prevention

The code below is what I am seeing when I 'Inspect' or 'View Source' of my website. It doesn't appear inside the code when I open the actual source file, only when inspecting or viewing the source code. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<div style="position: absolute; opacity: 0; visibility: hidden;">
<p>You may come across various types of real pokie games in Australia. People may play them just for fun or for real money. If you aren't able to come to a brick and mortar casino pick a real online pokie site. Experts from <a href="https://fancasinos.com/online-pokies/real-money/">https://fancasinos.com/online-pokies/real-money/</a> can assist you since they are experienced in playing pokies online for real money.</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a security issue, scan your website with OWASP ZAP.
Here is the link to [ZAP official site](https://www.zaproxy.org/). After completing the scan you can generate a security report of you site. It provides a dialog that can be accessed via menu "Report / Generate Report" menu item.

Comment: Thanks, however, this doesn't appear to be free software and this is not something I really want to be spending $ on.  Any good free options out there that you're aware of? I did try Sucuri SiteCheck and nothing was found.